# Issue on One by One Increment on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-number-spinner-on-click-hold). Why is click on event causing to jump to odd numbers instead of incrementing one by one?

```
$(function() {
    var action;
    $(".number-spinner button").mousedown(function () {
        btn = $(this);
        input = btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input');
        btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('button').prop("disabled", false);

        if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
            action = setInterval(function(){
                if ( input.attr('max') == undefined || parseInt(input.val()) < parseInt(input.attr('max')) ) {
                    input.val(parseInt(input.val())+1);
                }else{
                    btn.prop("disabled", true);
                    clearInterval(action);
                }
            }, 50);
        } else {
            action = setInterval(function(){
                if ( input.attr('min') == undefined || parseInt(input.val()) > parseInt(input.attr('min')) ) {
                    input.val(parseInt(input.val())-1);
                }else{
                    btn.prop("disabled", true);
                    clearInterval(action);
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    }).mouseup(function(){
        clearInterval(action);
    });
});
```

Comment: It works fine for me, incrementing/decrementing one number at a time. However, if I hold down the mouse it keeps going, so possibly you're holding the button down long enough to trigger the event twice?

Comment: Strange! I tried in FireFox and Edge and they are acting same, adding num 2 number at one click!

Comment: If you are wanting it to just be per click, why not change the handler to onclick instead of mousedown?

Comment: It works fine, but 50 ms is a short time so in some cases, "clicking" will give enough time to increment twice. For an optimal UX, you would increment immediately on the mousedown, then wait for a longer time (maybe 500 ms) to start the continuous increment and then wait for 50ms between 2 of these.

Comment: @Pete, thanks for comment changing the event handler type just create a fast sequence of increasing numbers to the Max

Comment: That's because you only clearInterval on `mouseUp`..   In fact if you want per click, why are you even using setInterval.?

Comment: If you want it so that when the mousedown is active it keeps incrementing / decrementing, you might want to look into using a debounce rather than setInterval.  lodash has a nice debounce you could use.

Comment: @MonaCoder - with onclick and no need for intervals: https://www.bootply.com/JyLoc4N2Dj, if you want to keep your mousedown, changing your intervals from 50 to around 65 seems to sort out the double number jumping problem

Comment: Thanks Pete, this is exactly what I was looking for